# t-sql join but keep the row of joined table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to keep joined row as header on the top row? The main query is much complex with cte-hierarchy query and multiple joins. What I need is to left the joined tables always at the top to use them as a header.

Sample table:

```
create table temp_items 
(
    grp nvarchar(2),
    item nvarchar(2)
);

insert into temp_items (grp, item) 
values ('G1', 'I1'), ('G1', 'I2'), ('G1', 'I3');

create table temp_groups 
(
    grp nvarchar(2),
    name nvarchar(18)
);

insert into temp_groups (grp, name) values ('G1', 'Group 1');
```

```
select g.grp, g.name, i.item 
from temp_groups g
join temp_items i on g.grp = i.grp
```

Desired output:

```
grp | name    | item
----+---------+----
G1  | Group 1 | NULL
G1  | Group 1 | I1
G1  | Group 1 | I2
G1  | Group 1 | I3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just writing `join` is equivalent to an `inner join` and thus you **will not** see any rows that don't have a corresponding value in `temp_items i` ..... you will need to use a proper `left (outer) join` to get what you're looking for ....

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` won't change the behaviour here, @marc_s . The OP is, effectlvely, looking to "create" an extra row where the `JOIN` to the other table isn't completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be to use `VALUES` to "create" an extra row:

```sql
SELECT g.grp,
       g.[name],
       i.item
FROM dbo.temp_groups g
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(g.grp),(NULL))V(grp)
     LEFT JOIN dbo.temp_items i ON v.grp = i.grp;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04733ec29e8c45de7b08b5c2f97c33ee)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Is is possible also to add a empty row (filled with NULLs) with cross apply?

Comment: It's not the `APPLY` that's doing it, @user2463808, it's the `VALUES` table construct. You can create what ever row you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to simply add a query on the group table and assign a sorting index to it, such as the following example should clarify:

```
WITh cte AS(
  SELECT 1 AS srt, g.grp, g.name, NULL AS item
    FROM temp_groups g
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS srt, g.grp, g.name, i.item 
    FROM temp_groups g
    INNER JOIN temp_items i on g.grp = i.grp
)
SELECT grp, name, item
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY srt
```